how to send a selenium script to a selected browser in the selenium hub, without involving other nodes and stopping them
how to send a selenium script to a selected browser in the selenium hub, without involving other nodes and stopping them.
hi,
There is a question.
I use js, selenium hub and docker
The network where the browser containers are running is located in docker. Multiple instances of different browsers (node) can be running at the same time
There is a task to send the selenium script only to the selected browser. without involving other nodes or stopping them.
If there is such an opportunity, I would like not to use the selenium hub at all, but to send selenium instructions directly to the browser container

Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.
